# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: (number you input but negative)

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

When I input any amountNumber > 4 it appears:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: (number I input but negative)
    at finder_pairs.finder_program_main.main(finder_program_main.java:19)

```
            System.out.println("How many numbers will you input?");
    Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amountNumbers = amount.nextInt();
    if (amountNumbers < 4)
        System.out.println("Error you need to input at least 4 numbers");
    System.out.println("Write the numbers: ");
    Scanner numbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    int repetition = amountNumbers;
    do {
    int[] num = new int[amountNumbers];
    int num1 = num[0-amountNumbers];
    int num2 = num[1-amountNumbers];
    int num3 = num[0-amountNumbers];
    int num4 = num[1-amountNumbers];
    if (num1 + num2 == num3 + num4)
        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + "is equal to " + num3 + " + " + num4);
    repetition-- ;
    }while(repetition > 0);
    amount.close();
    numbers.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `num[0-amountNumbers]` What were you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
int num1 = num[0-amountNumbers];
```

You have try to call the index of `0-amountNumbers` *which you specify must be 4 or greater*. This will mean that this will always cause an `indexoutofboundserror` as zero minus a positive number will be zero, which is not a valid `array` index. I'm not sure what you were intending to do with this line but you have to make sure that the index that you call will be 0 or greater